# Django media url is not resolved

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls, django-settings

I've read about this problem on google and stack, but nothing cleared up the problem.
I'd like to show image from imagefield.
settings

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',

                    ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Названия товара")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Цена")
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Фото", upload_to='item')
    alias = models.SlugField(verbose_name="alias  категория")
```

view

```
def item(request, alias):
    try:
        tovar = Item.objects.get(alias=alias)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Not Found ')
    context = {

        'tovar': tovar,

    }
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string("item.html", context))
```

template

```
<div class="container">
    {% for item in tovars %}
        <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="float:left;height:320px;width:150px;margin-left:40px;">
            <br/>
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <img class="img-product" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt=""/>
                    <h2 id="{{ item.id }}" class="value">{{ item.price }}</h2>
                    <p class="name">{{ item.name }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart ">
                    </i>Add to cart</a>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I open in browser this view and it doesn't load image.
http://127.0.0.1:777/media/item/quu3_Lj1KUoR.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
Internal Server Error: /media/item/quu3_frHnLS9.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\gited\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 235, in get_response
  response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "E:\gited\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'Http404' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Folder contains item folder, and that folder has that image. Seems that links to images are real, but it rejects to load them.
How to fix this?

Comment: Is this the *actual* code that you are using? The template code doesn't correspond to the context variables in the view. The error is also what would occur if you were doing `return Http404` instead of `raise Http404`.

Comment: @solarissmoke, i changed urls to simple urlpatterns +=static(...), other code is actual. But i do raise in my view. So why imget gets error for http404, when i do nothing about raising that error for image? I'll doublecheck